# Finding logical duplicate records

Tags: sql

I was interviewed with the question in SQL and Data in table are as follows:

```
city1 city2   distance
pune  mum     200
mum   delhi   1000
mum   pune    200
blr   pune    200
```

to fetch Logically Duplicate records, as in above table record 1 and 3 is logically duplicate

SQL query , please help

Comment: Note that tables have _rows_, not records.

Comment: Also _specify_ the expected result. And show us your query attempt.

Comment: Not able to solve so asking

Comment: I'll give you a hint: Join the table with itself and compare city1 of one table with city2 of the other and vice versa. What if the distances differ? Are the rows still logical duplicates?

Comment: o/p should be like: CITY1 CITY2 DISTANCE
pune mum 200
mum delhi 200
blr pune 200

Comment: Hey, not as a comment. Edit your question instead

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `EXISTS` to see if the "Logically Duplicate" exists.

```
SELECT d1.*
FROM distances d1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM distances d2
              WHERE d1.city1 = d2.city2
                AND d1.city2 = d2.city1)
```

If desired, you can add `AND d1.distance = d2.distance` to the subquery's `WHERE` clause.

Core ANSI/ISO SQL, and expected to work on any dbms.

Answer (score 1):

Your question raises some questions regarding the table design. Is

```
pune  mum     200
pune  mum     300
```

concidered a duplicate? I assume here that city1, city2 is unique. If the distance between A and B should be the same as the distance between B and A you can prevent duplicate rows by adding constraints like:

```
UNIQUE ( city1, city2 )
CHECK ( city1 <= city2 )
```

That said, you can find duplicates as:

```
SELECT LEAST(city1, city2), GREATEST(city1, city2)
FROM t
GROUP BY LEAST(city1, city2), GREATEST(city1, city2)
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

Some DBMS use min, max instead of least, greatest

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lJq34v8G)